# Pandas: df["<tab> find completion, df.loc["<tab> WON'T find any completion. Is it normal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read somewhere that the preferred way for accessing dataframes columns is through the method `.loc`, but I found some drawbacks and I am wondering if it is normal.

Say that I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_csv("MyFile.csv")
```

and assume that the dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
      ColA   ColB  ColC
Time
0.0    9.2  -3.5   2.0
0.1   10.2  -0.9   1.1
0.2    4.3   2.1   4.2
```

If I type `df["` and then hit `TAB` the autocompletion kicks in and I can choose the column name from a pop up list whereas if I type `df.loc["` and then hit `TAB`, then nothing happens and I am wondering if it is a normal behavior.

Also, it seems that if the column name are tuples, e.g.

```
      ('ColA','X')    ('ColB','Y')    ('ColC','Z')
Time
0.0        9.2            -3.5            2.0
0.1       10.2            -0.9            1.1
0.2        4.3             2.1            4.2
```

then I can access them with e.g. `df[('ColA','X')]` but I cannot with `df.loc[('ColA','X')]`.
I am running `iPython 7.2.2` (console) on a `Windows 10` machine, if it may help.

Comment: `df.loc[something]` is for index `something`, `df.loc[:, something]`is for column.

Comment: Right! But I just tried `df.loc[:,` TAB and it does not work. :( Also, `df.loc[:,('ColA',X)]` does not work.